# package sun.security.ec does not exist

Tags: java, security, class, jar, sun

I'm trying to use `sun.security.ec` module in Java on Win7. When trying to compile, it gives this error:

> package sun.security.ec does not exist

Where does `sun.security.*` reside in terms of a .jar file? Where can I download the .jar file?

Comment: Are you using a Sun JVM?

Answer (score 6):

It is part of the JDK (at least JDK6 has it), should be in `classes.jar` (where `java.lang.String` is and almost everything else).

However, you should not be accessing these implementation-specific classes directly. You should be able to use this provider using the standard interfaces, such as [java.security.spec.ECParameterSpec](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/spec/ECParameterSpec.html).

Comment: Also worth noting is that they're not guaranteed to be in all implementations, nor in a future release of one that has it now.

Comment: classes.jar? You mean rt.jar, right? (at least that's the correct file for Sun/Oracle Java)

Comment: @Sami. Maybe. On the Mac, it is `classes.jar`.

Comment: Ah ok, my bad, I guess I knew that, but had forgotten. On Windows/Linux where the Sun/Oracle version is distributed it's rt.jar.

Comment: In my day, it was `classes.zip`.